# How to apply ratio test to prove convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2^n n!)^2}{(2n)^{2n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, ratio

Can someone please help me with this
I know that we should use the ratio test but can you show me the steps in detail
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2^n n!)^2}{(2n)^{2n}}$$

And I stuck here
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{(2^{n+1}(n+1)!)^2}{(2n+2)^{2n+2}}.\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2^n n!)^2}\right|$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n+2)^{2n}}\right|$$
how should I proceed from here?

Comment: The second one won't converge: $n!^3$ grows much more quickly than $3n!$, and so almost all the terms in the second sum will be greater than 1.

Comment: This is not a site for which you can petition to have your homework done for you.

Comment: @MarkViola I agree with you but it's also possible they are genuinely lost, in which case it's more constructive to write a comment like "What have you tried, where did you get stuck using the comparison test?"

Comment: @TSF  And you have now asked those questions.

Comment: @MarkViola : we need to have the "Not homework site" and "show what you have done" as automated conditionals for the new users to read and agree to for their first n posts. This is getting really tedious of anyone just dumping and not thinking before posting.

Comment: @jimjim Indeed.  It seems to be getting worse, but perhaps I've just become less patient.  I'm sure I've answered a lot of questions in the past that were likely homework problems.

Comment: @MarkViola : It is not you, I too have noticed an increase in home work requests without having shown any attempt.  Should put this into meta as a request that new users to explicitly confirm that  they have shown some work or attempt before post being submitted.

Comment: Sorry guys this is my first time that i used this platform. This is not a homework and i didn’t know how should I evaluate the limit as n approached to infinity.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you don't know how to do limit? then why not learn the limit first before looking at convergence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the ratio test, we have to evaluate the limit:
$$ L := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right | $$
If $L <1$, the series converges; if $L >1$, it diverges; if $L=1$ or the limit does not exist, we cannot conclude anything with the ratio test.
Now consider the first series; we have:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right | =  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left | \frac{(2^{n+1} (n+1)!)^2 (2n)^{2n} }{(2^n n!)^2 (2n+2)^{2n+2}} \right | = \frac{1}{e^2} < 1$$
Thus, the first series converges. Similarly, you can see that the second series diverges.

EDIT: to evaluate the limit, rewrite it as follows:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{2n+2}(n+1)! (n+1)! 2^{2n} n^{2n}}{2^{2n} n! n! 2^{2n+2} (n+1)^{2n+2}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left ( \frac{n}{n+1} \right )^{2n} =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left (1- \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^{2n} = \frac{1}{e^2} $$
where at the first passage we have simplified, and in the last one we have used a well known limit for the exponential.

Comment: The part that i have problem is how to evaluate this limit can you describe how did you evaluate this?

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: thank you very much